# How to get rid of unwanted line in output - Java

Tags: java, string

The goal of this program is to print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line. But for some reason when I go to output, there's always an [extra line shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZAlJ.png).

```
import java.util.*;

public class program1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Init Scanner
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; x >= i; i++){ //Loops 
            String word = sc.nextLine();
            String temp1 = "", temp2 = "";
            for (int j = 0; word.length() > j; j++){
                if (j % 2 == 0){
                    temp1 += word.charAt(j);
                } else if (j % 2 != 0){
                    temp2 += word.charAt(j);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(temp1 + " " + temp2);
        } sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can really understand what's the problem with your output. Besides, you forgot a sc.nextLine() right after your int x = nextInt() at the beginning. You need to get rid of the new line in the Scanner's buffer after reading your integer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
It throws:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
 at program1.main(program1.java:9)
at me.

Comment: The fix for that was to change 
for (int i = 0; x >= i; i++){ // Loops
to 
for (int i = 0; x > i; i++){ // Loops

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to get rid of the "extra line" is doing

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

instead of

```
int x = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: Always welcome! @Fupeng-Zhao if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. See here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Using **sc.nextLine()** method
I changed `for (int i = 0; x >= i; i++){ // Loops` to `for (int i = 0; x > i; i++){ // Loops`
Which fixed the `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` error

Using **int x = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());** method
I also have to change I changed `for (int i = 0; x >= i; i++){ // Loops` to `for (int i = 0; x > i; i++){ // Loops` as it is making me input three strings instead of the desired two.

Thank you to all the people who helped me!